# Manual migration of a non versioned Managed Object Model

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, core-data

This question title might look duplicate but please read through my problem as it is different but it is related to Core data migration.

I had uploaded the first version of my app on Apple store near about 2 months back and then uploaded second version last month.

Now the problem i am getting is that my newer version is getting crashed due to core data as new version includes addition of some attributes in the existing entities.

At that time i was unaware of such migration process but now i don't know what to do as my app is live.

I have to upload a new version which must have compatible version of core data.
Please guide me through this.

```
-(void)checkNeedForMigration{
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]              URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ISB.sqlite"];
NSLog(@"database:%@",storeURL);


NSError *error = nil;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator   *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]     initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

NSDictionary *sourceMetadata =
[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:storeURL error:&error];

NSManagedObjectModel *destinationModel=[psc managedObjectModel];
BOOL pscCompatibile = [destinationModel isConfiguration:Nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];

NSManagedObjectModel *sourceModel=[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil forStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];

NSMappingModel *mappingModel =[NSMappingModel mappingModelFromBundles:nil forSourceModel:sourceModel destinationModel:destinationModel];

NSMigrationManager *migrationManager=[[NSMigrationManager alloc]initWithSourceModel:sourceModel destinationModel:destinationModel];

NSDictionary *optionDic=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, nil];

BOOL ok=[migrationManager migrateStoreFromURL:storeURL type:NSSQLiteStoreType options:optionDic withMappingModel:mappingModel toDestinationURL:storeURL destinationType:NSSQLiteStoreType destinationOptions:optionDic error:&error];}
```

Now getting null mappingModel...

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: You need to test your app to see if the lightweight migration will safely upgrade your old files. There are Apple docs available that describe the upgrade options. If all you are doing is adding some additional attributes then you may be able to get away with lightweight migration. Do a search on Core Data versioning and migration.

Comment: I have already tried that but i am confused as i have already changed the structure of database...i am confused which versions i should put in..

Comment: Describe the changes to the data model-- it's important.

Comment: hey i have come to know that i have to do custom migration as 1st version of my app was not version controlled.. but i am not sure how to do it..